# Error Message displayed in footer. Notice: ob_end_flush(): fail in public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3464

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody help me in finding the solution for this kind of error in Wordpress?

> Notice: ob_end_flush(): fail in /home/yatra/public_html/wp-         includes/functions.php on line 3464

Answer (score 0):

Apparently zlib.output_compression is active on your server.

It's part of a bug #18525. You can do the following:

1. Disable zlib.output_compression, by adding: `ini_set('zlib.output_handler', '');`
2. Apply the patch provided there and report back on that ticket if it works.
3. Disable notices.

Comment: can u please elaborate on how to disable ?? where do i add that code?

Comment: You can insert it in a plugin or in your functions.php @theme